# Quick question: CSS alteration for DMs on social media site

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

I am trying to get the image to line up above the sent message as you would have it in most standard DMs: https://prnt.sc/IR__3qyiXqlI (what I want it to look like)

But for some reason, the text attached to the image proceeds to layer itself beside the image rather than below the image, as shown in the screenshot below. When I add float: right; to my CSS the image and the text layer horizontally in a strange manner: [what it looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmoB4.png)

Ideally, the image should be on the same side as the texts from the person who sent the image and should be just above the message that was attached to the image (as is commonplace).

The HTML doc the DMs are stored on:

`thread.html`:

```
> {% extends 'landing/base.html' %} {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
> 
> {% block content %}
> 
> <div class="container">
>     <div class="row">
>         <div class="card col-md-12 mt-5 p-3 shadow-sm">
>             {% if thread.receiver == request.user %}
>                 <h5><a href="{% url 'profile' thread.user.profile.pk %}"><img class="rounded-circle post-img" height="50" width="50"
> src="{{ thread.user.profile.picture.url }}" /></a> @{{ thread.user
> }}</h5>
>             {% else %}
>                 <h5>@{{ thread.receiver }}</h5>
>             {% endif %}
>         </div>
>     </div>
> 
>     {% if message_list.all.count == 0 %}
>     <div class="row my-5">
>         <div class="col-md-12">
>             <p class="empty-text">No messages yet.</p>
>         </div>
>     </div>
>     {% endif %}
> 
>     {% for message in message_list %}
>     <div class="row">
>         {% if message.sender_user == request.user %}
>         <div class="col-md-12 my-1">
>            
>             <div class="message-sender-container ms-auto">
>                 {% if message.image %}
>                 <img src="{{ message.image.url }}" class="message-image-sent" />
>                 {% endif %}
>                 <div class="sent-message my-1">
>                     <p>{{ message.body }}</p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>             
>     
>         </div>
>             {% elif message.receiver_user == request.user %}
>             <div class="col-md-12">
>                 {% if message.image %}
>                 <div class="message-receiver-container offset-6">
>                      <img src="{{ message.image.url }}" class="message-image-received" />
>                 </div>
>                 {% endif %}
>                 <div class="received-message my-3">
>                     <p>{{ message.body }}</p>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>             {% endif %}
>         </div>
>     {% endfor %} 
> 
> 
>     <div class="row">
>         <div class="card col-md-12 p-3 shadow-sm">
>             <form method="POST" action="{% url 'create-message' thread.pk %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
>                 {% csrf_token %}
>                 {{ form | crispy }}
>                 
>                 <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
>                     <button btn btn-light type="submit">Send Message</button>
>                 </div>
>             </form>
>         </div>
>     </div> </div>
> 
> {% endblock content %}
```

the relevant CSS file:

`style.css`:

```
.empty-text {
        color: #777;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        text-align: center;
}

.sent-message {
        background-color: #d7a5eb;
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        width: 25%;
        float: right;
}

.received-message {
        background-color: #cc64c3;
        color: #000;
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        width: 25%;

}

.message-receiver-container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 0;
}

.message-sender-container {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: auto;

}


.message-image-received {
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-width: 35%;
        height: auto;

}

.message-image-sent {
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-width: 35%;
        height: auto;
        float: right;
        
}

.shared-post {
        margin-left: 30px; 
}
```

Comment: When you use `float: right`, the elements stop being stacked. I'd use flexbox for placing the elements on the right, instead of using float.

Comment: Hi @EduardoTolmasquim. I've tried adding `display: flex;  flex-direction: column;` to the css file, and they are stacking correctly but now stuck to the left side rather than the right side. (see screenshot). https://prnt.sc/Arz7dLqoz47w  [This is what the CSS looks like now: https://prnt.sc/_hsAJjcGkKg7 ]

Comment: Now for each message, image or text, you can set the align-self: flex-end. If the message is being received, you can set align-self: flex-start. Notice that the flex container should fill the whole width.

Answer (score 0):

@Eduardo Tolmasquim

I've tried adding that and even with trial and error it didn't change anything. Despite this, I've managed to ~half way~ fix it, only problem is now the sent messages and received messages are on the wrong side! (i.e. the messages sent by the logged in user are on the left and the messages they received are on the right, on most apps like Whatsapp it is the other way round). This is what it looks like [now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7wDZ.png).

`thread.html`:

```
{% extends 'landing/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card col-md-12 mt-5 p-3 shadow-sm">
            {% if thread.receiver == request.user %}
                <h5><a href="{% url 'profile' thread.user.profile.pk %}"><img class="rounded-circle post-img" height="50" width="50" src="{{ thread.user.profile.picture.url }}" /></a> @{{ thread.user }}</h5>
            {% else %}
                <h5>@{{ thread.receiver }}</h5>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>

    {% if message_list.all.count == 0 %}
    <div class="row my-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="empty-text">No messages yet.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% for message in message_list %}
    <div class="row">
        {% if message.sender_user == request.user %}
        <div class="col-md-12 my-1">
            {% if message.image %}
            <div class="message-sender-container ms-auto">
                <img src="{{ message.image.url }}" class="message-image" />
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            <div class="sent-message my-3">
                <p>{{ message.body }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
            {% elif message.receiver_user == request.user %}
            <div class="col-md-12 offset-6">
                {% if message.image %}
                <div>
                    <img src="{{ message.image.url }}" class="message-image" />
                </div>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="received-message my-3">
                    <p>{{ message.body }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %} 

    <div class="row">
        <div class="card col-md-12 p-3 shadow-sm">
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'create-message' thread.pk %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form | crispy }}
                
                <div class="d-grid gap-2 mt-3">
                    <button btn btn-light type="submit">Send Message</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

`style.css`:

```
.empty-text {
        color: #777;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        text-align: center;
}

.sent-message {
        background-color: #d7a5eb;
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        width: 35%;
}

.received-message {
        background-color: #cc64c3;
        color: #000;
        border-radius: 30px;
        padding: 10px 25px;
        width: 35%;
}

.message-sender-container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 0;
}

.message-image {
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-width: 35%;
        height: auto;
}

.shared-post {
        margin-left: 30px; 
}
```